# How do you export a .OBJ file on blender WITHOUT mtl?

Tags: lwjgl, blender

I am making a 3d game with Java LWJGL. I use .obj files to load the models into my game but i dont make it read a separate .mtl file because it is really hard and im struggling to do it. So im trying to make the obj files in blender then exporting it as an obj. BUT there is an extra file which pops up called "player.mtl" and when i try to read just the obj format file my game cant process it :( 
This has been on my mind for a long time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Go to `File > Export > Wavefront (.obj)`.
2. In the `Export OBJ` menu in the lower left uncheck `Write Materials`.
3. Choose a file name and press `Export OBJ`.
4. Now you have only the obj without the mtl file.

Comment: @AlexSafayan That because this is literally what the MTL file does. It contains the materials. If you have an OBJ without MTL you will not have any material.